# KVLY-TV: Nepalese Edition

Tags: construction, mathematics

[image]

Standing 2063 feet tall, KVLY-TV is currently the tallest transmitting mast in the world.  Standing above the flatness of North Dakota, you might think it's in a safe place to stand.  But the Great Plains are subject to high winds, and the uniformity and thinness of the mast's frame is poor defense.

I don't usually do handwavium, but in this scenario, I may have to because I've been thinking of putting the tallest transmitting mast on the peak of the highest mountain.  (Highest, not tallest--that title goes to Mauna Kea, Hawaii.)  Against rugged terrain, freezing weather and high winds, let's say that it was constructed out of carbon nanotubes, or a pyramidical base--I could go as far as shielding the whole thing with a force field.

Why put KVLY-TV atop Everest?  It's all due to the simple equation that the taller you are, the higher you are situated in, the further the length of the transmission.

So when one puts KVLY-TV atop Everest, what would the maximum length--or radius--of the transmission be?

Comment: Depends on wavelength, transmitted power, echo...

Comment: Why isn't Chimboarzo the highest then? It is the highest compared to the center of the Earth. Or maybe Kilimanjaro? Everest is surrounded by other high mountains, Kilimanjaro stands alone 4000m+ above the surrounding plains and so is the highest relative to its surroundings. A radio tower on Everest isn't really going to provide a lot of service to anyone...

Comment: That would depend on the length of your antenna, not its location....

Comment: If you want a really tall antenna, you can also use a blimp.  See TV Marti, where the US used a blimp to broadcast to Cuba.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_y_Televisi%C3%B3n_Mart%C3%AD

Comment: This is physics with speculation and is on-topic here.

Comment: People still do broadcast TV?  The obvious (and already implemented) solution is to make your antenna REALLY tall - like 22K miles or so - and broadcast from geostationary orbit.  It's why a lot of my neighbors have these little dishes on their houses :-)

Comment: @Green real life questions are on topic only if the aim is to create fictional world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is based on [line of sight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-of-sight_propagation), basically how far is it to the horizon until the Earth is blocking the transmission, this can be found fairly easily based on height given: $D = 1.23*\sqrt{h}$, with D being the distance to the horizon in miles and h being the height in feet.

Mt Everest is 29,029 feet tall + 2063 feet for the broadcast tower total height of 31092 feet. plugging that in I get a distance to the horizon of 216 miles (348 km).

The broadcast range will be a little longer than that given the thickness of the atmosphere propagates the signal.  The same Wikipedia page lists service range found using $D = 1.41*\sqrt{h}$ pushing it out to 248.6 miles (400 km).  This is a pretty big range for a Earth based transmitter and is marked on the map below with a circle.

This is of course assuming that all the land around you is lower than your raised point, which for Everest is not true, Mount Everest is part of a large range know as Tibetan Plateau which would greatly decrease this distance to the north of Everest to something close to the range of only the towers height (~60 miles or ~100 km).
[image]

This would likely not be very economical for Nepal, but it would likely be useful for the much more populated lowlands in India or Bangladesh. Which is only improved by putting the antenna closer to those countries (inside their borders) in the foothills of the Himalayas not on peaks like Everest.

[image]

Also, large antenna's like this require infrastructure in place to function, things like a fairly large amount of electrical power, ground based communication lines and methods to access the site for periodic maintenance and inspection.  The top of Mount Everest has none of those things, making it a terrible site location for a broadcast antenna.